# ParseInt Error - Java

Tags: java, parseint

Why am I getting this error? I've tried changing many aspects of the code, but could not figure out the error. Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;


public class Problem1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int ogarank = 177;
        int ogbrank = 129;
        int ogcrank = 11;
        int newarank = 0;
        int newbrank = 0;
        int newcrank = 0;
        int input = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Your Number");
        input = scan.nextInt();

        input = input % 100;
        newcrank = separate(input, newcrank);
        input = input % 100;
        newbrank = separate(input, newbrank);
        input = input % 100;
        newarank = separate(input, newarank);

    }

    public static int separate(int input, int rank)
    {
        rank = input;
        return rank;
    }

    public static int convert(int ogrank)
    {
            int digit1;
            int digit2;
            String convert;
            digit1 = ogrank / 10;
            digit1 = digit1 * 16;
            digit2 = ogrank % 10;
            digit2 = digit2 * 1;
            convert = ("" + digit1 + "" + digit2 + "");
            ogrank = convert.parseInt();
    }
```

error: cannot find symbol

```
        ogrank = convert.parseInt();
                        ^
```

symbol:   method parseInt()

location: variable convert of type String

Comment: It's probably because [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) doesn't have a `parseInt()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is `Integer.parseInt()`

`convert` is a `String` type variable and doesn't have `parseInt()` method

Comment: Thank you I tried that earlier but it wasn't working. It's working now though, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change the method should have a String `param` like this:

```
 ogrank = convert.parseInt();
```

To:

```
  ogrank = Integer.parseInt("String to parse");
```

**Description:**
This method is used to get the primitive data type of a certain String. parseXxx() is a static method and can have one argument or two.

**Syntax:**
All the variant of this method are given below:

```
 static int parseInt(String s)
 static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
```

**Parameters**:
Here is the detail of parameters:

s -- This is a string representation of decimal.

radix -- This would be used to convert String s into integer.